# Can I split templates on a Quarto page so hero has one template and the rest of the content has another?

Tags: html, css, quarto

I'm building my personal website on Quarto. As far as I know, I can either have the separated image/links section on the left (with the trestles template, as shown in the screenshot) OR I can have everything in the main, middle section. Ideally, I'd like to have a hero section with the profile picture and the links in the left side, but then have the next paragraph be justified across the page again so there isn't just a whole bunch of empty space on the left side. Is there any way to do that in Quarto?

This is the code I put at the top to get the left-hand column, and to have everything in the middle there is no header. I'd like a mix of both if possible My website is at davidenders.me if it helps to see the current state of the homepage.

```
---
title: "David Enders"
about:
    template: trestles
    links:
        - icon: linkedin
          text: LinkedIn
          url: 
        - icon: twitter
          text: Twitter
          url: 
        - icon: github
          text: Github
          url: 
        - icon: instagram
          text: Instagram
          url: 
        - text: "{{< fa envelope >}} Email"
          url: 
        - text: "{{< ai orcid >}} ORCID 0000-0003-3131-0864"
          url: 
        - text: "{{< ai google-scholar >}} Google Scholar"
          url: 
image: media/headshot.jpg
---
```

[image]